# Is there anyway to send a file to AWS s3 bucket other than using Multipart form data using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, http, httprequest, form-data

I want to make a "PUT" request to a Signed URL but that signed URL doesn't support multipart form data. The request is containing media content( videos, images, sound files). I have tried converting media files to a fileStream and then upload but no luck.
Code is as follows.

```
public async Task<string> UploadFilee(string filePath)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);

            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("video/mp4");
            form.Add(fileContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(filePath));

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AWSAccessKeyId", " *Data goes here* ");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Signature", " *Data goes here* ");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-amz-meta-media_id", " *Data goes here* ");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-amz-meta-name", " *Data goes here* ");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-amz-meta-system", " *Data goes here* ");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", " *Data goes here* ");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-amz-security-token", " *Data goes here* ");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-amz-tagging", " *Data goes here* ");

            var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(mediaUploadURL, form);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: 90 percent sure there would be a c# api

Comment: Use the S3 client for C#. That can do multipart. It is also possible to generate signed multipart URLs, but it isn't supported natively in the S3 client library (though I last checked about 4 years ago).

Comment: It looks like signing multipart URLs might also be part of the SDK now: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/717

Answer (score 0):

if anyone else got this problem too, found the method. This is written to read a video file from a location and upload it to the signed URL passed.

```
private string UploadMediaFile(CreateMediaEntryResponseModel createMediaEntryResponseModel, string mediaFilePath)
        {
          
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(createMediaEntryResponseModel.signedUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            httpRequest.Method = "PUT";
            using (Stream dataStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                FileStream getfileStream = new FileStream(mediaFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                var buffer = new byte[getfileStream.Length];
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(mediaFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        dataStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            HttpWebResponse response = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                GetMediaUploadStatus(createMediaEntryResponseModel.mediaId);
                return "OK";
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {

                return "BadRequest";
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {

                return "Forbidden";
            }
            return null;
        }
```